# Is there any plugin similar to electron-vue for react?

Tags: reactjs, electron

Ideally, it should be able to encapsulate the electron-builder and related webpack parts, only two commands are exposed dev: electron / build: electron

But in fact, the electron-react-boilerplate template is too complicated, and did not need so many functions at first, but this template is to pile all the functions at once.

---

My generation found a repository https://github.com/nateshmbhat/electron-react-ts-starter, but this directly divided them completely, and did not consider the problem of code reuse. . .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `generator-react-app-electron` on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-react-app-electron).

> This generator produces a non-ejected create-react-app project that is configured to run out-of-the-box with electron and a few other handy features

It provides `start` and `build` scripts that have been configured for running and building electron. Without ejecting. It also provides all essential features to develop an electron app (e.g. splash screen, entry points, ..).

Also you could use this template directly without using the generator: https://github.com/neutrinog/react-app-electron-template